# Sum of all of the numbers in row n of Pascal’s triangle? Explain why this happens, in terms of the way the triangle is formed...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Just to clarify there are two questions that need to be answered:

1)Explain why this happens, in terms of the way the triangle is formed.

2) Explain why this happens,in terms of the fact that the combination numbers count subsets of a set.

I know the sum of the rows is equal to $2^{n}$. However I am stuck on the other questions. I also have to assume I don't know the binomial theorem just yet.

I thought my explanation would be just add up the numbers in the rows, but I'm not sure if that is even what I need to do.

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Adding up the rows only tells you that they do add up to $2^n$ (but only the ones you actually check; you can't check them all).  It doesn't explain *why* they add up to $2^n$.  They are asking you *why* this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Notice the first row has sum $1=2^{0}$, every other row is recursively defined to be the previous row added to itself under the shift map which is a bijection hence the sum of every row $r_{n+1}=2r_{n}$ where $r_{i}$ is the $i^{th}$ row. Solving the initial condition and the recurrence relation yield that the sum of every row is $2^{n}$.
2. In terms of subsets the sum of the $n^{th}$ row is the sum of all subsets of size $k<n$. This is the same as all subsets of n since a subset of n can not have $n+1$ elements hence $2^{n}$ from elementary set theory.

Comment: Thank you this does help me!

Comment: For the second point, I'd say that it is the sum of all subsets of size k less or equal to n, not just less than n - assuming that you are counting the rows with n=0 for the first row.

Answer (score 7):

For any subset of a set of $n$ elements, and for any element of that set, the subset either contains that element or not. Hence, there are $2^n$ different subsets for any set of $n$ elements.

This is of course the sum, with $i$ ranging from $0$ to $n$, of the number of different subsets with $i$ elements, of which there are $n \choose i$ ... Which we know as the $i$-th entry of the $n$-th row in the triangle.

So: $\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} =2^n$, and therefore the sum of all entries in row $n$ equals $2^n$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Nixie777 You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 6):

Every element in row $n$ contributes to exactly two elements in row $n+1.$

Answer (score 2):

Use this problem as a gateway to learn one of the central *tricks* in all of Mathematics: Counting things in different ways to obtain a result that may not be obvious otherwise.

Say you have $n$ light switches in a row. Let's count the total number of different on/off configurations. On the one hand, each switch can be **on** or **off**, so there are $2^n$ configurations.

But we can count differently, grouping configurations in categories; namely, we can count how many configurations have $0$ **on** switches, then how mny have $1$ **on** switch, then how many have $2$, and so on, until we count how many configurations have $n$ **on** switches.

The consecutive answers are $\binom{n}{0}$, $\binom{n}{1}$, $\binom{n}{2},\ldots,\binom{n}{n}$, so the equality is *proved*. More to the point, the equality is *explained* as coming from counting something in two different ways.

The punchline is that you can *understand* the equality as encoding something about the internal structure of configurations of $n$ switches. Hopefully you find such notion inspiring.

Answer (score 2):

In case you already know that the entries in Pascal's triangle are the **binomial coefficients**, i.e., that the $k$th entry in the $n$th row, $n\choose k$, is the **coefficient** of $x^k$ in the expansion of the **binomial** $(1+x)^n$, then the sum of these coefficients is simply the evaluation at $x=1$, i.e., 
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}1^k=(1+1)^n=2^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

If $a^n_k$ is the $k$th element of the $n$th row, then the triangle is defined by $a^0_0=1$ and $a^{n+1}_k=a^n_k+a^n_{k-1}$ for $n\ge 1$ (we also need to specify that $a^n_k=0$ for $k<0$ or $k>n$).

Then we can compute the sum of the elements in row $n+1$ by $$\sum_k a^{n+1}_k=\sum_k(a^n_k+a^n_{k-1})=\sum_ka^n_k+\sum_ka^n_{k-1}=2\sum_ka^n_k$$

Combine this with the fact that the sum of the terms in the first row is $1$, and this shows that the sum of the $n$th row is $2^n$.

Of course, I've been sloppy here by not including the bounds of the sum and not keeping track of what happens around $k=0$ and $k=n+1$, but a little more attention to detail will make this into a rigorous proof of the identity.