# How many total different possible static combinations exist out of a collection of $n$ items ($0$ included, $n∈[N]$)?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, notation

What is the cleanest formula, succinctly and broken down?

when *n*=0, *a*=1

when *n*=1, *a*=1+1 = 2

when *n*=2, *a*=1+2×1+1 = 4

when *n*=3, *a*=1+C(3,2)+3×1+1 = 1+3+3+1 = 8

when *n*=4 *a*=C(4,4)+c(4,3)+C(4,2)+c(4,1)+C(4,0) = 1+4+6+4+1 = 16

(Pascal's triangle rows)

when *n*=n, *a*=C(*n*,n)+C(*n*,n-1)+C(*n*,n-2)+…+C(*n*,n-n)

$$a_n=\sum_{i=0}^n  \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Does this simplify or expand to basic operations (exponentiation andor factorials, multiplication, addition) onto *n* without the *k* term (and possibly without sigma operator)?

Comment: Spoiler: yes they do! See if you can visually see a pattern in terms of $n$. Then try to prove it. If you need a hint -- think about what the summation you wrote down means, in plain language; from that, a fairly-natural succinct version of that emerges. See if that's enough to work with for now.

Comment: Looking at the RHS shows a pattern, powers of 2. So the long binomial quotient is equal to 2^n. Fascinating!   found this https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2343622/819279 post helpful, as well as this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Entries_in_Row_of_Pascal%27s_Triangle#Proof_2 resource.

Comment: Yep, the on-switch/off-switch intuition in that post is excellent -- exactly what helped me reason about this problem.